# AWK: Get the line where the maximum of a column value occurs

Tags: bash, awk

I am interested in the maximum value of the 5th column. But, I also want to be able to capture the 6th and the 9th values of that row into an array. How do I do this?

The command below tries to get only the 5th column value.

```
myVar=$(bash myScript.sh | awk -v max=0 '{if($5>max){max=$5;max6=$6;max9=$9}}END{print $5}')
```

Edit: print $5 is printing the maximum of the 5th column.

Thanks.

Comment: [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output but ask yourself this - what does `max=$5` do and what does `END{print $5}` do?

Comment: Regarding `Edit: print $5 is printing the maximum of the 5th column.` - no, it's not. It's printing either the value of the 5th column on the last line read or it's printing a null string or it could be doing something else depending on your awk implementation as it's undefined behavior per POSIX. What it's definitely NOT doing is printing the maximum of the 5th column. Again - post sample input/output so we can help you.

Comment: Why are you populating variables `max`, `max6`, and `max9` if you never print them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want awk (or anything else) to return multiple values back to a shell script, then you have to actually print them in the awk script **and** read them into shell variables using `read` (or into a shell array using `mapfile` - also known as `readarray`).

BTW, since you're using bash, run `help read` or `help mapfile` for details on them.

e.g. the following uses `read` and [process substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_substitution) to read the values into shell variables `$max5`, `$max6`, and `$max9`:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

read -r max5 max6 max9 < <(bash myScript.sh |
  awk '$5 > max5 { max5=$5; max6=$6; max9=$9 }
       END { print max5, max6, max9 }' )

echo "max5 = $max5"
echo "max6 = $max6"
echo "max9 = $max9"
```

---

BTW, I don't have your `myScript.sh` so I tested with something much simpler - which also demonstrates that this method will work with **any** program or function that outputs 3 values on one line, separated by whitespace:

```
$ read -r max5 max6 max9 < <(awk 'BEGIN{print 1,2,3}')
$ printf "%s\n" "$max5" "$max6" "$max9"
1
2
3
```

Answer (score 2):

Given an input file like the following (doesn't matter if the values are positive or negative but using all negative is an important test as often people forget that can happen and write scripts that assume at least 1 value is greater than 0 which works fine during initial testing and then fails cryptically 6 months later in the field given real values):

```
$ cat file
a b c d  -5 foo e f bar
a b c d  -3 is e f stuff
a b c d -17 this e f here
```

This is how to print the 5th, 6th, and 9th values (using `cat file` in place of `bash myScript.sh` which I obviously don't have):

```
$ cat file | awk '(NR==1) || ($5>m[5]){ split($0,m) } END{ print m[5], m[6], m[9] }'
-3 is stuff
```

and if you want them stored in a shell variable, then it's simplest to just store them in a shell array, e.g. this may be all you need depending on the values of those fields:

```
$ arr=( $(cat file | awk '(NR==1) || ($5>m[5]){ split($0,m) } END{ print m[5], m[6], m[9] }') )

$ declare -p arr
declare -a arr=([0]="-3" [1]="is" [2]="stuff")
```